# Xamarin Webview - show custom error when network is not available

Tags: xamarin.android

When a web page is not available, it shows default webpage not available error, I want to detect when a link is clicked if internet is available. Is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin

This is a cross platform way of checking network connection in Xamarin. It can also detect the type of connection currently active. It is very very easy to get up and running.

As for your solution - when that link is clicked, you can check for a network connection using the plugin then, if there is a connection proceed to the web view otherwise, display an error.